# "These findings are critical [to inform/for informing] future research"

Tags: word-choice, verbs, prepositions, to-for, gerund-vs-infinitive

In this sentence, would you use "to inform" or "for informing"?

> These findings are critical ______ future research

Likewise, would you use "to understand" or "for understanding" in the following?

> These results provide a powerful framework _____ existing patterns.

This is a question that comes up a lot in science writing: when do you use the "to" vs. the "for" version of a verb? Is there a word for these two different uses?

And is there a rule for deciding which one is correct? They often get used interchangeably, but I can't find any hard rules for deciding between the two.

People often use the "to" version because it sounds less passive, but I find it more ambiguous and a bit clunky, but I can't find any actual sources to say which is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The linguistic structure we are discussing is basically this:
Discovery/information ==> informs/enlightens ==> something else.

The former provides something to enable the latter. Generally then, "for" is a good word to describe this relationship. The findings provide something *for* informing future work. The results provide something *for* understanding patterns.

"To" can carry some very different meanings, but in this context, I think it actually takes on a meaning that is nearly identical to the "for" phrase. The value of the findings is "to inform". The results help us "to understand". I see very little difference, and don't think it matters much which is used. But I do think that "for" more exactly communicates the relationship the sentences describe.